# Linear Independence and Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm confused as to how I can find the basis from the following question. I know that basis has to be linearly independent and it has to span all of $R^4$. I know that each $x$ is it's own vector and they are being multiplied by a scalar. But how can I translate that into three other vectors that span the subspace of $R^4$. Also, wouldn't there need to be a 4th vector involved to completely span $R^4$?

Comment: The subspace spanned by this (hyper)plane is 3 dimensional as the four variables are not independent. If, for example, x+y = 0 then y = -x and any point on this line is of the form (x, -x) = x(1, -1). A basis for the subspace spanned by x+y = 0 is the single vector (1, -1). That should be enough, but I'm sure someone will write out the full answer if you wait a few minutes:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul said, you have one constraint, so the result should be three dimensional. So really, you're looking to find three linearly independent vectors that all satisfy that equation and you're done. An easy way to go about it would be to start with the following vectors, which are surely independent:
(1,0,0,a),(0,1,0,b) and (0,0,1,c).
All that's left to do is solve for a,b and c. You'll get some fractional values from your equation.
To get nicer-looking vectors, you could scale the vectors by -9 (the coefficient of x4) to get integer coordinates, yielding:
(-9,0,0,9), (0,-9,0,5),(0,0,-9,4).